# How to create a parent listview that handles selecting items etc.?

Tags: flutter, listview, inheritance, dart

I'm trying to create a base listview, that takes care of clicking on a listtile and selecting items.
It then shows a checkbox per item and keeps track of how many items have been selected.
All my lists are going to need this feature so it makes sense to put this inside some base class.
But how would I do this using flutter?

The following code contains part of the logic:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.separated(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
  itemCount: widget.models.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(onLongPress: () {
      selectMode = true;
      widget.models[index].selected = true;
      selectCount++;
      setState(() {});
    }, onTap: () {
      if (selectMode) {
        if (widget.models[index].selected) {
          widget.models[index].selected = false;
          selectCount--;
        } else {
          widget.models[index].selected = true;
          selectCount++;
        }
        if (selectCount == 0) {
          selectMode = false;
        }
        setState(() {});
        return;
      }
    });
  },
);
```

}

I have no idea how to continue from here. This obviously works perfectly fine when putting it all inside one specific list. But it makes much more sense to have it in a base class and simply inherit this behaviour.
Is it possible to move this logic into a base class and still be able to define different ListTiles for other lists?
I read that you are not supposed to inherit widgets in flutter at all, so I really don't know how to proceed, but there certainly must be a better way than having to copy/paste this logic into every new list.

Edit:
ListTile showing a checkbox based on selectMode:

```
ListTile(
        onLongPress: () {
        },
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 84, 158),
          child: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.white, size: 40),
        ),
        title: Text('Title $index'),
        subtitle: Text('${models[index]}'),
        trailing: Visibility(
            visible: selectMode,
            child: models[index].selected == true
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 84, 158))
                : Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 84, 158))),
        onTap: () {
        });
```

This is another thing that *should* be part of the "base", else you would have to paste this in every listview you create. So when I have some custom listview widget, which already has a listTile built in to handle to clicking and showing the checkbox, how would a new listview be able to have a different styled listTile, possibly without a leading icon etc.?

I have created a little DartPad to show how it works:
https://dartpad.dev/98d3f9b01c5b048d90aad3467aa3954e

Now image you want the same behaviour in every list you ever create, without having to write the same code again and still be able to use different kind of listTiles, or even add actions to onTap event etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to achieve, but from what I do understand, it seems you are trying to reuse a particular widget.

To do this, all you have to do is create a new Stateful widget that contains only the code for the ListView. Then to make sure it is "dynamic" (i.e, it can use different lists of Objects/Models), you'll have to create a parameter in its constructor.

Also, if you want to access the total from another widget, you'll need to use a callback.

```
class MyCustomSelectableListView extends StatefulWidget {
   // Variable for your list of models. Replace Object with your Type
  final List<Object> models;

  // Callback to get the value of selectCount from another widget.
  final Function(int) getSelectCount; 

  // Passing the variables through a constructor.
  const MyCustomSelectableListView({this.models, this.getSelectCount, Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCustomSelectableListView createState() => _MyCustomSelectableListView();
}

class _MyCustomSelectableListView extends State<MyCustomSelectableListView> {

  // Your variables
  bool selectMode = false;
  int selectCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      itemCount: widget.models.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(onLongPress: () {
          selectMode = true;
          widget.models[index].selected = true;
          selectCount++;
          setState(() {});
        }, onTap: () {
          if (selectMode) {
            if (widget.models[index].selected) {
              widget.models[index].selected = false;
              selectCount--;

              // Using the callback
              widget.getSelectCount(selectCount);
            } else {
              widget.models[index].selected = true;
              selectCount++;
              
              // Using the callback
              widget.getSelectCount(selectCount);
            }
            if (selectCount == 0) {
              selectMode = false;
            }
            setState(() {});
            return;
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Reusing this piece of code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Object> myListOfModels = [Object(), Object()];
    return Scaffold(
        body: MyCustomSelectableListView(
            models: myListOfModels,
            getSelectCount: (count) {
              print(count);
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to have one base listview, that enables e.g. selecting items. So after that whenever I need a listview, I can just reuse my base listview and selecting will always just work. But since the tap and longpress event are part of the listTile, I have no idea how I can now use different listTiles in different lists. In Android, you would simply extend the adapter and redirect these events to your list activity, which you then extend for new lists. But in flutter it's not possible like that.

Comment: Have you tried the code above? 

I personally think you’re over complicating things. My takeaway is that you want to reuse functionality right? 

Also, is your code for selecting items working right now? Right now the code looks pretty messy, and there are much better and simpler ways to implement selecting items in a list. I’d be happy to help you if you’d like.

Comment: I have updated the question, it is working pretty good. I'm happy if you know an easier way for this issue. But I imagine the more complex my app gets, the more often I will end up having to move code to a base class, and so far I don't really know how that is supposed to be done in flutter.